# ASP.NetCore OData DTO $expand navigation ICollection property results in ArgumentException

Tags: odata, automapper, dto, expand, ef-core-2.2

I am using Entity Framework with OData to get data from my mysql database but I don't want to expose database entites to the user, so I've created some DTO's and map them with Automapper.
My Problem is that everything works fine except loading entities with $expand (Collections).

Entities and DTO's: (in my project the dto's and domain models do not look the same, this is only for better reading):

```
public partial class Product
{       

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }        

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }     
    public virtual ICollection<ProductPrice> ProductPrices { get; set; }   
}

public class ProductDTO
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductPriceDTO> ProductPrices { get; set; }
    public virtual CategoryDTO Category { get; set; }
}

public partial class Category
{     
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }         
}

public class CategoryDTO
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public partial class ProductPrice
{
    public string VendorId { get; set; }
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
}

public class ProductPriceDTO
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Vendor")]
    public string VendorId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual VendorDTO Vendor { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductDTO Product { get; set; }
}
```

The models are created the following way:

```
 public IEdmModel GetEdmModel(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(serviceProvider);
        builder.Namespace = "Functions";            
        //category
        builder.EntitySet<CategoryDTO>("Categories").EntityType.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Count().Page();
        //product
        builder.EntitySet<ProductDTO>("Products").EntityType.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Count().Page();
        //productprice
        builder.EntitySet<ProductPriceDTO>("ProductPrices").EntityType.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Count().Page();
return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

Automapper profile:

```
public AutoMapperProfile()
    {            
        CreateMap<Product, ProductDTO>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Category, conf => conf.AllowNull())
            .ForMember(dto => dto.ProductPrices, dest => dest.MapFrom(x => x.ProductPrices))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.ProductPrices, dest => dest.ExplicitExpansion())
            .ForMember(dto => dto.ProductPrices, conf => conf.AllowNull());
        CreateMap<ProductPrice, ProductPriceDTO>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Product, conf => conf.AllowNull())
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Vendor, conf => conf.AllowNull());            
    }
```

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
[ODataRoutePrefix("Products")]
public class ProductsController : BaseODataController
{
    private readonly IProductService ProductService;
    private readonly IProductPriceService ProductPriceService;

    public ProductsController(IMapper mapper, IProductService productService, IProductPriceService productPriceService) : base(mapper)
    {
        ProductService = productService;
        ProductPriceService = productPriceService;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<ProductDTO> Get(ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        var query = ProductService.QueryProducts();
        string[] includes = GetExpandNamesFromODataQuery(queryOptions);
        if (includes != null && includes.Length > 0)
        {
            return query.ProjectTo<ProductDTO>(null, includes);
        }
        return query.ProjectTo<ProductDTO>();           
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute("({key})")]
    public IQueryable<ProductDTO> Get([FromODataUri] string key, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        var query = ProductService.QueryProducts().Where(x => x.Id.Equals(key));
        string[] includes = GetExpandNamesFromODataQuery(queryOptions);
        if (includes != null && includes.Length > 0)
        {
            return query.ProjectTo<ProductDTO>(null, includes);
        }
        return query.ProjectTo<ProductDTO>();
    }        
}
```

As I mentioned above every query works fine ($select, $filter, $orderBy, $count). Also the navigation to the Category (CategoryDTO) works great.

But when I call the following:

> https://localhost:44376/odata/Products('631794')?$expand=ProductPrices

I get:

> ArgumentException: Expression of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Tuple`3[Dentiqo.DTOModels.ProductPriceDTO,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.MaterializedAnonymousObject,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.MaterializedAnonymousObject]]'
>   cannot be used for parameter of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Dentiqo.DTOModels.ProductPriceDTO]&#x27;
>   of method
>   &#x27;System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Dentiqo.DTOModels.ProductPriceDTO]
>   ToListProductPriceDTO'
>
> Parameter name: arg0

If I change the Get Method to IEnumerable and add ToList() everything works fine. But I can't do this because the query is very slow. Is it possible that the 2 Keys (VendorID and ProductID) are not correctly mapped?

Comment: Hi, shouldn't `return builder.GetEdmModel();` be the last line in `GetEdmModel`? Why don't you setup a small, but full project in GitHub repo (or something else) that  we can download and reproduce the issue?

Comment: Yes the last statement is return builder.GetEdmModel(); I forget to copy it.
Yes I can try to make a small project on GitHub.

Comment: I have just created a project on GitHub to test my issue. https://github.com/leithi/ASPNetCoreOdataExpand.git

When I call:

 https://localhost:44376/odata/Products('product1')?$expand=ProductPrices

I get the issue

Comment: Thank you. I've reproduced it. Unfortunately the problem is either in OData, EF Core, or both. The problem seems to be `ToList()` generated by AutoMapper for `ProductPrices` projection. I've tried changing the DTO collection type to `IEnumerable<…>` and used hand written `Select` w/o `ToList()`, which fixed the issue. From the other side `ToList` in projection is EF Core 2.x recommended way of avoiding N + 1 query. AM generates it automatically and there is no simple way to let it not do that. I really have no good advice, hopefully someone else could help you. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please share the code?
I think about to forget DTO's and only work with domain models...